# Custom PPT viewer for android

Tags: android

Currently I am using https://github.com/itsrts/pptviewer-android as PPT viwer. But with this library slides are not displayed for some files. So could you suggest any other library for the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Currently it's e.g. not clear if you're looking for a library to use with your own app – or for a ready to use app (meeting which requirements?).

Comment: Do you want a software that could open PPT's or a library to include in your app that opens PPT's?

Comment: I need library to include my app.